# .NET MVC4 - Running app inside of parent app

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to determine the best way to do this.

Basically, I have a child app that runs inside of a parent app in IIS.  I want to be able to run this app inside of the parent app (using the same layout and functionality)

What is my my best bet for doing this?  Running the app in an iFrame?  Loading the app through jQuery into a div?  Or should I create a web service that sends the parent app's layout to the child app?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are talking about here is composition. There are a whole bunch of different composition patterns you can apply which will each have pros and cons. Stack overflow isnt really a great place to get an answer on what the 'best' pattern to use is but here are a few I can think of:

**Server side composition patterns**

- **Shared Layout file with MVC**

  - This method uses a layout file from a DLL shared by both sites to render all pages
  - Its pretty easy to implement but means you need to release both sites when the file changes
  - This encourages strong coupling between the sites (which is bad)
- **Sub request based rendering**

  - Only have a parent site on the internet, at run time request blocks of content from an internal url for the child site
  - Loose coupling in terms of content but strong coupling in terms of urls
  - many child sites can be pulled in and are not coupled to each other
  - parent/child sites can be released independently

**Client side composition**

- **IFrames**

  - really lo-fi, so easy to implement
  - has a bunch of really aweful stuff to deal with in terms of css and javascript between the frame and parent
  - Generally considered by devs as a bad idea (opinion)
  - Coupling only by URLs, sites can be released independantly
- **Ajax in content**

  - Do an ajax request for components from other sites as the page loads
  - Increases page load times and gives ui flicker as bits load in
  - Pretty easy to implement and manage
  - Coupling only by URLs, sites can be released independantly

Answer (score 0):

You could either use [Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your app, iFrame, or simply open a new browser tab for your child app.

If you want to include your project in a dll, you could compile all the views into a dll and reference it with your parent app, [this](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/) web site explains how this can be done.

Comment: I'm not sure if Area is the right way to go - Areas help in organizing your Controllers etc. within a single application, whereas the question is about multiple applications.

Comment: Then i would suggest using DLL's or iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use the way to make empty layout of your child application and render it to the div of your parent application with JQuery. IFrame should stay in the past.